Run SAS Macro within R studio
I have a SPS SAS macro that generates SAS dataset as it's output. I am using this output in my R code for applying further analysis methods on it. I want to reduce this dependency of R code on SAS for generating that output data. Is there any way to call the SAS macro in R studio and run it as is inside R studio? I have heard that there are ways to run SAS syntax inside R environment but not sure about how can I run the whole SPS SAS macro within R environment!! Any help on this is appreciated.
I tried SASPY package but it reportedly works only for simple SAS syntaxes and not whole SAS macro.

Probably not. It would likely be easier to figure out how to rewrite the SAS macro in R (yes, there are things that SAS can do that R cannot, but not many ...)

Have you looked into sasr? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sasr/index.html. With saspy you can run any SAS program with the submit() method, and in sasr this is the run_sas() function, so your macro should work fine.

Also if you have IML, you can run your R code in SAS if you wanted to go that route.

Do you want all the code to run in R? Or are you trying to use R to call SAS to run the macro? It's not easy in the general case to completely re-implement the SAS programming language inside of R. There may be package which might wrap calls to SAS for you but then you still have a dependency on SAS and a valid license for it. I can't tell if you're trying to completely eliminate SAS or not.

@MrFlick is correct, you can use essentially a batch process/remote submission to have R run the SAS code using the SAS application but otherwise will need to convert the code if you're trying to remove SAS from the process entirely.
